# How do I change the font color of one word in the middle of a sentence, without ruining my text animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have my text fading up into the page using @keyframes, translateY. However, there is a single **word** in the middle of my sentence that was given a different color, using `<font color="#08255e">`. The color has changed, but now the single **word** is appearing immediately when the page loads, instead of appearing during its animation!

How can I make it appear with its correct timing, like other words in the sentence?

CSS, HTML or JavaScript preferred.

```css
 .anime001 {
  animation: text 2.5s 1 1s forwards;
}

 .anime002 {
  animation: text 2.5s 1 3s forwards;
}

 .anime003 {
  animation: text 2.5s 1 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes text {
  0% {
    display: none;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    transform: translateY(200px)
  }
  100% {
    color: #05004e;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="textanime1">
  <h2 class="anime001">Optimize your brand's digital footprint</h2>
  <h1 class="anime002">Let's
    <font color="#9500ff">fluff</font> up your business.</h1>
  <h3 class="anime003">Websites | Social Media | Logos | Flyers</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `font` element is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) and you can not trust on it behavior. 
You can use a `span` and style it with your css like this:

```css
.anime001 {animation: text 2.5s 1 1s forwards;}
.anime002 {animation: text 2.5s 1 3s forwards;}
.anime002 span { color: #9500ff;}
.anime003 {animation: text 2.5s 1 4s forwards;}
@keyframes text {
  0%{ display: none;
      letter-spacing: 20px;
      transform:translateY(200px)
  }
  100%{ color: #05004e;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="textanime1">
  <h2 class="anime001">Optimize your brand's digital footprint</h2>
  <h1 class="anime002">Let's <span>fluff</span> up your business.</h1>
  <h3 class="anime003">Websites | Social Media | Logos | Flyers</h3>
</div>
```

EDIT

If you want the span will change the color after the animation end you can set time with javacript. Something like this:

```js
changeFontColor = window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('.anime002 span')[0].style.color = '#9500ff';
    }, 4500); // you can adjust this in order to set when style will start
```

```css
.anime001 {animation: text 2.5s 1 1s forwards;}
.anime002 {animation: text 2.5s 1 3s forwards;}
.anime003 {animation: text 2.5s 1 4s forwards;}
@keyframes text {
  0%{ display: none;
      letter-spacing: 20px;
      transform:translateY(200px)
  }
  100%{ color: #05004e;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="textanime1">
  <h2 class="anime001">Optimize your brand's digital footprint</h2>
  <h1 class="anime002">Let's <span>fluff</span> up your business.</h1>
  <h3 class="anime003">Websites | Social Media | Logos | Flyers</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Much cleaner code, but the word "fluff" still jumps out when the page loads, then it rejoins the animation.

Comment: What do you mean by jumps?

Comment: Setting time with javascript works perfectly, thanks Meshu!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace deprecated <font> with <span> for example, also and add default font color in "0%" keyframes.